# Taking Screenshot of failed Fest JUnit test

Tags: ant, junit, fest

I am currently writing Fest Junit test cases that will be later ran on a Hudson test server.  I would like to have them take desktop screen shots if any test case fails.  I found this url that has a tutorial on how to set this up: http://fest.codehaus.org/Taking+Screenshots+of+JUnit+Test+Failures but the tests don't even run locally.

Here is a skimmed down copy of the java code that I am attempting to run:

```
@RunWith(GUITestRunner.class)
public class AddingNewUserTest extends FestTest {
    @Before
    public void setup(){
       super.setup(constants.users.name);
    }

    @After
    public void cleanup(){super.shutDown();

    }

    @GUITest
    public void testAddingNewUser() throws InterruptedException{
      //java code
}
```

And my JUnit Ant task that I am attempting to run:

```
<target name="run.tests" description="Runs all the junit tests.">
    <echo message="Run the tests"/>
    <taskdef resource="festjunittasks" classpathref="classpath" />
    <junit printsummary="true" errorproperty="tests.failed" failureproperty="tests.failed" fork="true" showoutput="yes">
         <classpath refid="classpath" />
          <formatter classname="org.fest.swing.junit.ant.ScreenshotOnFailureResultFormatter" extension=".xml" />

          <batchtest todir="${test.output.reports.test.dir}" unless="testcase" fork="true">
                 <fileset dir="${output.mainclasses.dir}" includes="**/AddingNewUserTest.class" excludes="**/FestTest.class,**/DefaultsTest.class"/>
           </batchtest>
        </junit>

        <festreport todir="${test.output.reports.dir}">
              <classpath refid="classpath" />
              <fileset dir="${test.output.reports.test.dir}">
                     <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
               </fileset>
               <report format="frames" todir="${test.output.reports.dir}/html" />
         </festreport>

        <antcall target="kill.server"/>

</target>
```

Any help would be great.

[image]

A screen shot of the error thrown by Junit in the report

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution that I found after stumbling upon some source code on the internet (if anyone stumbles upon this thread):
the  java code:

```
@GUITest
public void testAddingNewUser() throws InterruptedException{
      //java code
```

needed to be

```
@Test
@GUITest
public void testAddingNewUser() throws InterruptedException{
      //java code
```

Everything else seemed to be correct